# New tab opens "No Internet page" and then redirects to website after short delay

Tags: networking, windows-10, google-chrome, dns, browser

Browser: Google Chrome
OS: Windows 10

When I click on a link in an email or other website that opens a new tab, instead of the webpage opening, I first get a "There is no internet connection page".

[image: IMG:]

After around 2/3 seconds the page automatically refreshes and redirects to the page requested. This happens on all sites, simple or complex.

There are no manual DNS settings on the browser, the IP "adapter settings" in Windows nor on the Broadband modem/router.

I am not even sure where to start to diagnose this. Please let me know where we can look.

Traceroute info is below:

```
~$: traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.169.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.254)  2.515 ms * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  136.hiper04.sheff.dial.plus.net.uk (195.166.143.136)  21.901 ms 22.799 ms  22.799 ms
 5  195.99.125.134 (195.99.125.134)  22.791 ms 195.99.125.142 (195.99.125.142)  27.760 ms 195.99.125.134 (195.99.125.134)  29.560 ms
 6  peer7-et-7-0-2.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.252.88)  29.563 ms  26.463 ms peer7-et-0-0-5.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.252.184)  18.312 ms
 7  109.159.253.75 (109.159.253.75)  16.904 ms  13.396 ms 109.159.253.189 (109.159.253.189)  13.794 ms
 8  * * *
 9  108.170.232.98 (108.170.232.98)  12.213 ms 216.239.56.192 (216.239.56.192)  9.776 ms 216.239.58.222 (216.239.58.222)  13.384 ms
10  209.85.241.95 (209.85.241.95)  14.270 ms  14.264 ms 74.125.242.114 (74.125.242.114)  12.039 ms
11  lhr25s26-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.14)  12.029 ms  9.209 ms 216.239.59.77 (216.239.59.77)  9.793 ms
```

Comment: What email client? What if you right click and open in new tab from a Chrome instance directly? What do you get if you run `tracert google.com` at the command prompt.Have you tried one of the free DNS services like googles 8.8.8.8? Do other machines on the same network have the same issue?

Comment: If you haven't entered specific DNS servers, then your ISP's are in effect. They can be a bit overwhelmed when you send a request, what with the lockdown and all, and take a second or two to redirect to the IP you're trying to reach. You can increase the timeout in Firefox, but to my knowledge, you can't in Chrome.

Comment: it is for gmail in the browser. the same happens for a right click and load. I think it might be related to issues with the internet in general and I have been doing some 24hr ping and speed tests to see how the stability is. Other machines have the same issues, but only the windows boxes. linux seems fine. wonder whether I should set a manual DNS server...